# Jackson2 Instant serialization

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Java 8 Date/Time APIs in my DTO objects sent to and from clients to the server. I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and its default Jackson 2. I added the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` module as a dependency. Still, the `Instant` instances are not serialized using the `InstantSerializer`, they are written as a nested JSON structure with two fields, `epochSeconds` and `nano`. As these two methods are discoverable as getters in the `Instant` class, I guess the default bean serializer takes care of this.

What I would like is to have `Instant` serialized as longs, just as a `Date` would have been. I'm not doing any extra customization of the `ObjectMapper`, so I kind of expected this to work without much fuss.